# Etymology of ギリシャ: what language does "girisha" come from?

Tags: etymology, katakana

I have trouble remembering that [Greece](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greece) is called ギリシャ.
Understanding the etymology behind would probably help me?

What is the etymology of the word ギリシャ?
What language(s) was the name inspired by?

Answer (score 5):

The [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3#.E5.9B.BD.E5.90.8D) offers an explanation, unfortunately not backed by any reference:

> ギリシャあるいはギリシアという名称は、ラテン語名の Graecia （グラエキア）がポルトガル語で Grécia （グレスィア）となり、これが宣教師によって日本にもたらされ変容したとされる。

So it seems that the Latin name of Greece is `Graecia` became `Grécia` in Portuguese, which in turn became what it is in Japanese when (Portuguese?) missionaries visited.

Comment: 精選版 日本国語大辞典 agrees that it's via Portuguese *Grécia*.